# string operation-appending a string to itself

Tags: c++, string, stl

My code has this part which is throwing me an error

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
s=s+",";

cout <<"string length is now "<<s.length<<endl;
}
```

I am simply appending the same string again and again 100 times to itself.
error is :

**line 23: Error: Taking address of the bound function std::basic_string, std::allocator>::length() const.**

could anybody tell me what is the wrong i am doing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `s.length()`, not `s.length`:

```
cout <<"string length is now "<< s.length() <<endl;
```

Note that `std::string::length()` is a function, not a variable.

I prefer `.size()` because it is consistent with all other containers. Other containers don't have `.length()` member function; only `std::string` has this function, along with `.size()` which returns the same value.

So if `std::string` has `.size()`, then why makes exception and use `.length()`? Why not use `.size()` consistently?  I would you to suggest use `.size()` instead of `.length()`:

```
cout <<"string length is now "<< s.size() <<endl;
```

Comment: "Why not use .size() consistently" Because std::string isn't really a container. It's a hodge-podge class which only positive feature (but it is an important one!) is that it is standard. Cheers,

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: What makes it a non-container? And what is the *definition* of container?

Comment: @Nawasz: Well std::string has apparently become a container in C++11. The standard library's containers are listed in C++11 §23 "Containers library" (id [containers]). In C++03 it talked only about the containers listed here (imposing requirements on them), while in C++11 it talks about the containers listed here "and in (21.4)", which is std::basic_string. OK, learned a second new thing today. Thnaks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

`length` is a *function,* not a member variable. You need:

```
cout << "string length is now " << s.length() << endl;
```

The error ("Taking address of ...") is because `s.length` is the address of the `length` function for the type of `s`, whereas you want to *call* said function and use the return value.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such thing as `string::length` publicly available to be called. Try this:

```
s.size()
```

OR

```
s.length()
```

Comment: And `std::string::length()`, it is an alias for `std::string::size()`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/length/.

Comment: well, i guess the OP is trying C# style property `length`, which is not available in c++. but `length()` is of course available.